# selecting secondary index by tuple of labels

Tags: python, pandas

I have some sales data indexed on `('dt', 'product_id')` like this:

```py
In [43]: sub.head()
Out[43]:
                           income
dt          product_id
2015-01-15  10016          23
2015-01-15  10017          188
2015-01-15  10018          NaN
2015-01-16  10016          188
2015-01-17  10025         1000
# this goes on and on...
```

how can I view the income of product `10016` and `10025` in between `2015-01-15` and `2015-01-16`? I tried to learn about pandas slicers [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) but couldn't get it right:

```py
In [44]: sub.loc[idx[start:end,[10016,10018]]]

KeyError: 'None of [[10055, 10158]] are in the [columns]'
```

## raw data

```py
import pandas as pd

product_order = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('order.csv')
odr = product_order.set_index(['dt','product_id'])
```

```py
dt,product_id,subsidy
2015-03-03 00:39:08+08:00,10029,50.00
2015-03-09 00:47:00+08:00,10016,55.00
2015-03-13 01:00:12+08:00,10029,23.00
2015-03-15 01:03:40+08:00,10016,21.00
2015-03-16 02:18:45+08:00,10016,52.00
```

Comment: why not use a dictionary? Or are you?

Comment: You've changed your data so what is the desired output now?

Comment: For instance the following is an example of how to slice: `odr.loc(axis=0)[idx['2015-03-08':'2015-03-14'],idx[10016:10030]]`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming here that `gp` is your groupby object already you can slice like the following:

```
In [146]:
idx = pd.IndexSlice
gp.loc[idx['2015-01-15':'2015-01-16'], idx[10016:10025]]

Out[146]:
dt          product_id
2015-01-15  10016          23
            10017         188
            10018         NaN
2015-01-16  10016         188
Name: income, dtype: float64
```

So you need to define an [`IndexSlice`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) for each level that you want to perform the row selection criteria on

Comment: I immediately tried your approach and pandas complain `TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.index.Index'> with these indexers [10016] of <type 'int'>
`, and my intention was to select only two product, not `10016:10025`

Comment: What is the dtype of 'product_id'? is it `str` or `int`?

Comment: You'll have to post raw input data and code to reproduce your df as it works for me

Comment: just updated my post, note that I've made mistakes in my question, it's not a pandas groupby object but a pandas DataFrame indexed on `['dt','product_id']`